# Improve ffmpeg video capture performance?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, debian, intel-edison

I'm running Debian on my Intel Edison and attempting to capture video through a USB webcam using ffmpeg. The command I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -y test.mov
```

I end up with an output similar to the following:

```
frame=  356 fps=  9 q=8.0 size=    1958kB time=35.50 bitrate= 451.9kbits/s du
frame=  658 fps= 10 q=8.0 size=    3403kB time=65.70 bitrate= 424.3kbits/s du
frame= 1282 fps= 11 q=8.0 size=    5571kB time=128.10 bitrate= 356.3kbits/s d
frame= 1285 fps= 11 q=17.0 size=    5783kB time=128.40 bitrate= 369.0kbits/s 
frame= 1288 fps= 11 q=19.0 size=    5951kB time=128.70 bitrate= 378.8kbits/s
```

where the first frame wasn't even taken until 35.5 seconds had passed. It claims fps = 9, but I was only able to acquire those five frames after two minutes.

I would like to know if there is any way to improve the performance (e.g., frame rate) of ffmpeg.

Comment: Have you tried setting `-threads` to something higher?

Comment: Just did. It seemed to have almost no effect.

Answer (score 0):

With latest Intel Edison Yocto [image](https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/hardware/edison/downloads) and FFMPEG from [here](https://github.com/drejkim/edi-cam) I am getting ~30-32 fps with the same command you shared

/home/root/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -y test.mov

frame=   19 fps=0.0 q=21.0 size=127kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=2235.7kbits/s speed=0.922x

frame=   34 fps= 34 q=20.0 size=207kB time=00:00:00.96 bitrate=1755.6kbits/s speed=0.96x

frame=   49 fps= 32 q=20.0 size=280kB time=00:00:01.46 bitrate=1565.2kbits/s speed=0.973x

frame=   64 fps= 32 q=20.0 size=351kB time=00:00:01.96 bitrate=1460.4kbits/s speed=0.978x

frame=   80 fps= 32 q=20.0 size=426kB time=00:00:02.50 bitrate=1396.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.994x

I have a UVC Logitech HD720p USB webcam. Are you getting same fps with your webcam on a PC? Give a quick try on the default Yocto image and also see what you are getting.